# Realocar elementos no DOM

Tags: javascript

Como faço para retirar um elemento de sua posição e realocá-lo no DOM?

**Por exemplo:** em uma `<ul>`, trazer o último `<li>` para o topo/primeira posição.

Eu vi isso no jQuery, com a função `appendTo()`, e gostaria de saber como fazer o mesmo com javascript puro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar o `.insertBefore()` a sintaxe é:

```
elementoPai.insertBefore(novoElemento, elmentoReferência);
```

#### Exemplo:

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var primeiro = document.querySelector('ul li:first-of-type');
var ultimo = document.querySelector('ul li:last-of-type');
ul.insertBefore(ultimo, primeiro);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Primeiro ?</li>
  <li>Meio</li>
  <li>Ultimo ?</li>
</ul>
```

ou de maneira mais compacta:

```
var ultimo = document.querySelector('ul li:last-of-type');
ultimo.parentNode.insertBefore(ultimo, ultimo.parentNode.firstChild);
```